# How do I remove objects containing NULL from a COLLECT() clause in a CYPHER query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've run into the following issue with this **Cypher** query. The overall results are returned in an array of objects, as intended. However, the `collect()` clause is giving me some trouble.

If `user` has no `myFriends` and  no `theirFriends`, an empty array should be returned. Otherwise, if `myFriends` and/or `theirFriends` has values, it should be a single array of objects of the combined friends, with the id property of the respective friend.

**Query:**

```
MATCH (user:User)
WHERE user.id IN ['1', '2', '3']
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[:HAS_FRIEND]->(myFriends:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)<-[:HAS_FRIEND]-(theirFriends:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[:HAS_TEACHER]->(myTeachers:User)
RETURN {
  name: user.name,
  friends: collect({id: myFriends.id}) + collect({id: theirFriends.id}),
  teachers: collect({id: myTeachers.id})
}
```

**Results in:**

```
[
  {
    name: 'Joe',
    friends: [{id: null}, {id: null}],
    teachers: [{id: null}]
  }, ...
]
```

**Desired result:**

```
[
  {
    name: 'Joe',
    friends: [],
    teachers: []
  }, {
    name: 'Jen',
    friends: [{id: '4'}, {id: '6'}, {id: '7'}],
    teachers: [{id: '8'}, {id: '9'}]
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you correct the syntax errors in your query? For example, `friends2` and `myTeacher` are not defined. Also, you don't really need the `WITH` clause.

Comment: Also, since the lists only contain ids, why do you need them to contain `{id: 'N'}` elements.? Why not just `'N'` elements?

Comment: Arrays of objects containing ids is the desired format for the returned results. I want to avoid adding a loop after returning the results.

Comment: Not sure we're on the same page. How is `[{id: '4'}, {id: '6'}, {id: '7'}]` better than `['4', '6', '7']`?

Comment: The results will need to be returned in this format. Changing it after returning them from neo4j would result in a double loop. If it helps, you can imagine returning a second or third property within the same object. e.g. `[{id: '4', name: 'Lisa'}, {id: '6', name: 'Mary'}, {id: '7', name: 'Jane'}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATED]

A really nice thing about your particular data model is: you can get all the `myFriends` and `theirFriends` elements with a single *undirected* relationship pattern: `(user)-[:HAS_FRIEND]-(f)`.

For example:

```
MATCH (user:User)
WHERE user.id IN ['1', '2', '3']
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[:HAS_FRIEND]-(f:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[:HAS_TEACHER]->(t:User)
RETURN {
  name: user.name,
  friends: COLLECT(DISTINCT f{.id}),
  teachers: COLLECT(t{.id})
}
```

So, no list concatenation is needed. Also, the `DISTINCT` option removes duplicate `friends` elements.

*By the way, this query also uses the neat [map projections](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/values-and-types/maps/#cypher-map-projection) syntax as suggested by @P.S., which avoids `null` values.*

Comment: For people passing by, the new link as of today for map projections is this one https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/values-and-types/maps/#cypher-map-projection

Answer (score 0):

An elegant solution using [map projections](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/maps/#cypher-map-projection-examples) and keeping the `OPTIONAL MATCH` clause.

```
MATCH (user:User)
WHERE user.id IN ['1', '2', '3']
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[:HAS_FRIEND]->(myFriends:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)<-[:HAS_FRIEND]-(theirFriends:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[:HAS_TEACHER]->(myTeachers:User)
RETURN {
  name: user.name,
  friends: collect(myFriends {.id}) + collect(theirFriends {.id}),
  teachers: collect(myTeachers {.id})
}
```